# ROS-Qt GUI - How to distribute the Threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface, ros

I'm working on a C++ Qt GUI to remote control a ROS robot. I've read that the `ros::spin()` command should be issued in a seperate Thread so I basically have the usual MainWindow derived from `QMainWindow` whose constructor sets up the GUI elements, makes the Subscriber Objects subscribe to their respective topic (e.g. `image_transport::Subscriber` for `sensor_msgs/Image` topics) and also starts another Thread. For that I have derived a "RosThread" class from `QThread` that doesn't do anything but starting a `ros:MultiThreadedSpinner` when `RosThread::run()` is called.

As you can probably tell, I'm not exactly experienced when it comes to programming in general so my question is, wether the basic concept behind my project makes any sense to you?
Especially should I leave the NodeHandle and the Subscriber Objects in the MainWindow and setup the Subscriptions from the MainWindow Constructor?

Relevant code snippets:

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), itLeft(nh), itArm(nh)
{
    //subscribe to cameras
    imageSubLeft = itLeft.subscribe("/camera_1/image_raw", 1000, &MainWindow::camCallbackLeft, this);
    imageSubArm = itArm.subscribe("/camera_2/image_raw", 1000, &MainWindow::camCallbackArm, this);

    pagestack = new QStackedWidget;

    page1 = new QWidget;
    grid = new QGridLayout;
    page1->setLayout(grid);
    pagestack->addWidget(page1);

    labelLeft = new QLabel;
    labelMid = new QLabel;

    grid->addWidget(labelLeft, 0, 0);
    grid->addWidget(labelMid, 0, 1);

    this->startSpinThread(); //starts the seperate Thread where run() is executed
    this->setCentralWidget(pagestack);
    this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
    this->setMinimumSize(1024, 768);
}    

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){}    
void MainWindow::camCallbackLeft(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr &msg){/*some code*/}
void MainWindow::camCallbackArm(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr &msg){/*some code*/}
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event){/*some code*/}  

void MainWindow::startSpinThread()
{
    if(rosSpin.isRunning())
    {
        return;
    }
    //rosSpin is an Object of the of QThread derived class
    rosSpin.start();
}
```

rosthread.h:

```
#ifndef ROSTHREAD_H
#define ROSTHREAD_H
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <QThread>


class RosThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RosThread();

protected:
    void run();

private:
    ros::MultiThreadedSpinner spinner;
};

#endif // ROSTHREAD_H
```

rosthread.cpp:

```
#include "rosthread.h"

RosThread::RosThread()
{

}

void RosThread::run() {
    spinner.spin();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <ros/ros.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "gui_node");

  QApplication app (argc, argv);
  MainWindow *win = new MainWindow();
  win->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, QThread is not intended to be used this way. Take a look at [this blog article](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) and [this example](https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage).

But anyway, I would suggest the standard C++ threads.
Add `std::unique_ptr<std::thread> thread;` to your MainWindow class instead of the `RosThread` object.
To start a thread, use `thread.reset(new std::thread([](){ static ros::MultiThreadedSpinner spinner; spinner.spin(); });`. The smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` will automatically delete the thread object although you shouldn't forget to use `std::thread::join()` or `std::thread::detach()` before the resetting/destroying your `std::unique_ptr` object.
Another solution would be to put the `ros::MultiThreadedSpinner` object into your MainWindow class and create a `std::thread` using `thread.reset(new std::thread(&ros::MultiThreadedSpinner::spin, spinner));`.

In my opinion, you should put you NodeHandle and Subscriber objects into another class and use an object of this class as a member of MainWindow if they don't belong directly to MainWindow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me towards that article, that was really insightful. I think I'll try to put the NodeHandle and Subscriber in another class, as you suggested! I guess it would make sense to put the callback-functions in the same class then?

Comment: I think so, yes. Always try to organize the members of classes in a way that makes sense and that every class has only one task.

Comment: I tried it but there are multiple problems. First of all the callbacks really belong to the MainWindow as they have to setup all the labels. Putting the Subscriber and NH in the other class doesn't seem to do the job: The window only opens after killing the process so there don't seem to be multiple threads?! I thought this might solve an annoying Segmentation fault problem I had but maybe I'm on the wrong track there anyways. Thanks a lot for your help though!

Comment: Sadly can't edit the coment above: I did manage to get it going the way described in the example you posted. I only put the spinner in the "worker-class" though, as mentioned already. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the Segmentation fault but at least I'm kind of doing it the "correct" way now!

Comment: When and where do you get the seg fault?

Comment: I can't really tell. Sometimes it happens right after the program start, sometimes only after 5 minutes. As to where, I could provide a gdb backtrace but I don't really understand what it tells me. I guess I should maybe post a different question.

Comment: Yes, if it's unrelated to this topic, you should ask another question. But what about this question, is it solved or do you still have some issues?

Comment: I guess it might be kind of related but I think people will tell me when I ask specifically about the segault. Anyways thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'd say it's related if it happens due to your multithreading. If that's the case, you could just edit your question. Otherwise, it's probably the best idea to ask a new one.

Comment: Yeah I don't really know where the issue lies so I already posted a new question.